# tikz node generating error

Tags: tikz-trees

Okey so I am doing my project with tikz, where is states and nodes. When I want to generate my node, it shows error message: Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected.

My code:

```
     \documentclass{article}


    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifPDFTeX
       \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
       \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
       \usepackage{lmodern}
    \else
       \ifXeTeX
         \usepackage{xltxtra}
       \else 
         \usepackage{luatextra}
       \fi
       \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \fi
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}


    \tikzset{
        state/.style={
               rectangle,
               rectangle split,
                rectangle split parts=2,
                 rectangle split part fill={red!30,blue!20},
               rounded corners,
               draw=black, very thick,
               minimum height=4em,
               inner sep=3pt,
               text width=2cm,
               text centered,
               },
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm,
                        semithick]

      \node[state] (A) {text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
      \node[state]         (B) [right of =A]{text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
      \node[state]         (C) [right of=B] {text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
      \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$q_c$};
      \node[state]         (E) [right of=D]       {$q_e$};
     \node[state]         (F) [right of= E] {$q_f$};

        \path (A) edge                node (C)
              (B) edge                node {OK} (E)
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: add a semicolon at the end

Comment: A `node` needs a label in braces, so `node (C)` will also throw an error.  Should be `node {not OK} (C)` or something.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Or empty braces :-) `node {} (C)`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you again, one more question how to make node text smaller and more centered to the node middle? Also maybe you have something to offer how to make bigger gaps between rectangles position belov and above?

Comment: @Holene: of course, in that case one could do away with the node entirely: `(C)`

Comment: Load the `positioning` library and say `below=<dimension> of <wherever>`. For the text, add e.g. `font=\small, text centered` to the node options.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with trees?

Comment: Why have you tagged this `tikz-trees`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that

It is wrong:      right of =A
The correct is:   right=of A

Problem:
    \node[state]         (B) [above right=of A,label=left:$v_2$]  {$5$};

No problem
    \node                (B) [above right=of A,label=left:$v_2$]  {$5$};

After \path the   ;   is necessary.

Now your code compile.

Below your code adjusted

```
 \documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
   \ifXeTeX
     \usepackage{xltxtra}
   \else 
     \usepackage{luatextra}
   \fi
   \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           rectangle,
           rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=2,
             rectangle split part fill={red!30,blue!20},
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           minimum height=4em,
           inner sep=3pt,
           text width=2cm,
           text centered,
           },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm,
                    semithick]

  \node (A) {text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
  \node (B) [right= of A]{text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
  \node (C) [right= of B] {text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
  \node  (D) [below right= of A] {$q_c$};
  \node  (E) [right= of D]       {$q_e$};
  \node  (F) [right= of E] {$q_f$};
    \path (A) edge                node {} (C)
          (B) edge                node {OK} (E);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}